# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute. VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, bots, irc

There are a lot of questions that are a duplicate of this question, but none of them seem to actually answer my specific problem.

I am writing an IRC bot, and i am adding users to a List(Of String) as you can see in the below code. However, when i want to go through a foreach loop of the users on another thread, i get the error in the title. I have even put a boolean in place to stop it from adding users, yet it still says it is being modified somehow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Before you read the code, keep in mind i am new to VB.net, and even if it messy, i'd prefer to not be bashed for it as i am new)

```
Sub Handler()
    handlerActive = True
    Dim list As New List(Of String)
    query = "SELECT * FROM " & channel.Substring(1)
    Try
        connHost.Close()
    Catch
    End Try
    connHost.Open()
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, connHost)
    Dim dataReader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    While (dataReader.Read())
        list.Add(dataReader.GetString(1))
    End While
    dataReader.Close()
    If (users.Count > 0) Then
        For Each user2 In users
            Try
                connHost.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            connHost.Open()

            query = ("UPDATE `" & channel.Substring(1) & "` SET `Amount` = Amount + 1 WHERE `Username`='" & user2 & "'")
            cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, connHost)
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to update user - " & user2)
            End Try
        Next
    End If
    connHost.Close()
    handlerActive = False
End Sub
```

Below here is where i add users to my List called "users"

```
If (handlerActive = False And users.Contains(user) = False And user.Trim().CompareTo("") <> 0 Or user.Trim().CompareTo("jtv") <> 0 Or user.Trim().Contains(" ") = False Or user.Trim().Contains(".") = False) Then
        users.Add(user)
End If
```

Comment: Read the First line please. Not to mention that is C#, and a custom class. This is just a List(Of String) (Doesn't have a .Values method)

Comment: Problem solved. I changed `For Each user2 In users` to `For Each user2 In users.ToArray()`

Comment: @ChrisCurtis: Be aware that you are actually crating a copy of users list. This can have a performance impact and users added during cycle are not included in iteration (probably desired but should be noted).

Comment: Thank you for that heads up. I will make sure that i am disposing of any unnecessary copies of the array.